# php - session lost after refreshing page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, session

So I am developing a login system for my website and I would like to change the navigation bar when the user is logged but I can't get it to work because the session keeps getting lost after I refresh the page to update the navigation bar. This is what I got in my login.php script:

```
if ($loginNumRows == 1) {
   echo 'true';
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['username'] = $loginRow['name'];
```

When this echoes 'true', the following javascript is loaded:

```
if (html == 'true') {
    window.location.href = "index.php";
```

I tried with "location.reload(true);" and it is still the same. And in the main page, where the navigation bar is, I make the following check:

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION))
            {...}
```

However this always returns false. Any ideas what to do? Thanks!

Comment: have you put `session_start();`

Comment: `session_start()` have to be in each visited pages, preferably at the beginning of the script.

Comment: @Lix i am talking about on the index page

Comment: put session_start() on the top of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, no need for javascript to redirect you to the index page. You can do it from PHP too:

```
header("Location: index.php");
```

So the login.php will look like this:

```
if ($loginNumRows == 1) {
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['username'] = $loginRow['name'];
   header("Location: index.php");
```

Note, that I have changed the order. As others **I strongly recommend to put session start above all of your code**.

And finally make sure that you have session started in the index.php file too(this should be also placed above all of your code ):

```
session_start();
```

EDIT: If you want to stick with your javascript method ( witch I highly not recommend ), than your login.php code should look like this:

```
if ($loginNumRows == 1) {
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['username'] = $loginRow['name'];
   echo 'true';
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have `session_start();` at the top of all your scripts.

Answer (score 1):

As previously stated above, I would first put session_start() above all other code on the page, not in the conditional statement.